# How to sort a list of N elements and then replace missing values between 0 to N with -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Sample Test Case

```
                     Input                                  Output

 - Test Case 1       3 1 4 2 5 0                            0 1 2 3 4 5
 - Test Case 2       4 7 -1 9 -1 5 3 -1 -1 -1           -1 -1 -1 3 4 5 -1 7 -1 9
```

you can see that the missing numbers are replaced with -1 in the place where they are missing (i.e in sorted manner) how can i achieve this output, I am able to get the input by

```
num = list(set((map(int, input().split()))))
num.sort()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @roganjosh They want a list like 3 2 and 0, and to order them. So they will get 0, 2 and 3. Then, as 1 is not there, place a -1 between 0 and 2. I think. I don't know honestly...

Comment: @roganjosh Given a list A of elements of length N, ranging from 0 to N. All elements may not be present in the array. If the element is not present then there will be -1 present in the array. Rearrange the array such that A[i] = i and if i is not present display -1 at that place.

Comment: @Aman I see. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the numbers from the input list in a *set*. Then to get the output list you can iterate over the range of numbers and check if they're in the set:

```
in_list = [4, 7, -1, 9, -1, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1]    
s = set(in_list)
out_list = [i if i in s else -1 for i in range(len(in_list))]    
print(out_list)  # [-1, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5, -1, 7, -1, 9]
```

Comment: I believe they want the list such as [3, 1, 0] to be ordered like [0, 1, 3]. Then, as two is not present, -1 will be put in its place. [0, 1, -1, 3]. So the list starts without -1. Correct me if I am wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(list):
    length = len(list) - 1
    unsorted = True

    while unsorted:
        for element in range(0,length):
            unsorted = False
            if list[element] > list[element + 1]:
                hold = list[element + 1]
                list[element + 1] = badList[element]
                list[element] = hold
            else:
                unsorted = True
    i = 0
    while i < range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i+1] - list[i] != 1 and list[i+1] != -1 and list[i] != -1:
            list.insert(i+1, -1)
            i = i - 1
        i = i - 1
    return list
list = [3,1,4,2,5,0]
print(sort(list))
```

Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Python list comprehension is a pretty simple concept. You can iterate over a list and fetch elements of the list based on your conditions.

Consider following example:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = []
for elem in old_list:
    new_list.append(elem)
print(new_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The code is basically creating a list from another. Nothing fancy here. But it is not `pythonic` way to do it. Let's do it `pythonic` way:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = [elem for elem in old_list]
```

This does exact same thing. But why we just didn't copy the `old_list` to `new_list` directly? Because list comprehension can be used to more than just copying elements as is. See this:

```
old_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = [elem+1 for elem in old_list]
print(new_list)  # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now you created a different list! You can do any operation on list elements to create a new one.

Since python also has ternary operation, it is possible to do this too:

```
a = 3 if x>2 else 4
```

It is short for this code:

```
if x>2:
    a = 3
else:
    a = 4
```

When you bring list comprehension and ternary operation together, you can solve your problem in just 1 line of code.

```
a = [1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5]
def zerofy(arr, n):
    return [-1 if 0<=elem<=n else elem for elem in arr]

zerofy(a, 2)
# [-1, -1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your answer to the OP and for those who may come across it in the future.

Comment: @hcoat, how is it now?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (if I am understanding your question correctly)

```
test1 = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0]
test2 = [4, 7, -1, 9, -1, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1]

print([i if i in test1 else -1 for i in range(0, len(test1))])
print([i if i in test2 else -1 for i in range(0, len(test2))])

>>>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>[-1, -1, -1, 3, 4, 5, -1, 7, -1, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure Python method would involve a list comprehension, `range` and `set`. If you are interested in performance for larger arrays, I suggest using a 3rd party library such as NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0])
b = np.array([4, 7, -1, 9, -1, 5, 3, -1, -1, -1])

def reindexer(x):
    res = np.arange(len(x) + 1)
    res[~np.isin(res, x)] = -1
    return res

reindexer(a)  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
reindexer(b)  # array([-1, -1, -1,  3,  4,  5, -1,  7, -1,  9])
```